# Python, Jupyter: function keeps looping asking for input instead of terminating after input is provided

Tags: python, function, loops, jupyter

I am writing code to output certain inputs to a text file to organize photos. I call a function that prompts for user input. The issue is that once input is provided, the function continuously loops and asks for input again. It does this without being inside a while loop. There is a while loop present in the function, but as you can see below, the while loop functions properly, and the erroneous loop actually loops through the entire function over and over. The following is the function in question:

```
def add_image_to_notes(code):

    x = input('Where is the image located (path of image file): ')
    y = input("Name the photo: ")
    
    for words in code:
        code1 = words.replace("imagepath",x).replace("imagedescription",y)
        
    with open('test1.txt') as old, open('test2.txt','a+') as new:
        for line in old:
            new.write(line)
            if 'word' in line:
                new.write(code1)
    i = 0
    while i < 1:
        cont = input("Continue coding? Yes or no: ")
        if cont == 'n':
            finished_coding()
            i += 1
            break
        elif cont == 'y':
            continue_coding()
            i += 1
        else:
            print('Invalid response. y or n.')
```

If I choose y, it works as designed. It runs the `continue_coding()` function, and the `add_image_to_notes(code)` does not loop.

If I choose n, however, the output is the following:

```
Where is the image located (path of image file): c:\sqlite\lion1.jpg
Name the photo: lion1
Continue coding? Yes or no: n
Where is the image located (path of image file):
```

It is supposed to go to a `finished_coding()` function, which simply renames the `test2.txt` file to `final.txt`:

```
def finished_coding():
    os.rename('test2.txt','final.txt')
```

The craziest part is that the `finished_coding()` function DOES execute properly, but the `add_image_to_notes(code)` function continues to loop and prompt for input, so I have to interrupt the kernel.

Seems like a bug, but I have no idea how to resolve. I tried adding a `break` statement after the `finished_coding()` function is called, but this did not resolve either. I also have tried forcibly closing the `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` files via `old.close`, `new.close()`, and I have tried to force the writing to the file via `new.flush()` commands, none of which prevented the function from looping. I have of course restarted Jupyter, and I have commented out my entire code line by line in an attempt to identify the problematic part of it, some of which broke the code and none of which prevented the loop. This only happens with this function. I have put the function in a cell by itself, as well as in a cell with the other functions listed. No avail.

I am willing to provide supplemental code or information if needed of course. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It would appear that `add_image_to_notes()` is being called in a loop - you haven't shown us the relevant code.

Comment: Got it. One moment, let me grab the code that calls it.

Comment: ```
for line in sets:
        if 'add image to file' in sets:
            add_image_to_notes('imagedescription is located at imagepath')
```

Comment: That loop makes no sense, at least not without more context... what is the point of looping over `sets`, whatever that might be, if you're not going to do anything with the current element of the loop (`line`)?

Comment: Good Lord. Jason that was the solution. I removed the for line in sets, works perfectly. I feel so dumb, thanks a lot man.